# View Binding not working in case of layer-list in android

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

In my project I am using View Binding to avoid findViewById() method calling. In gradle file I have enabled it as mentioned below :

```
  buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}

buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

It is working fine in case of UI. but in one of the UI I have drawable that is an xml consisting layer-list as mentioned below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorProgressBarBgWhite" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/progress_bar_radius" />
        <padding
            android:bottom="@dimen/progress_bar_bg_padding"
            android:left="@dimen/progress_bar_bg_padding"
            android:right="@dimen/progress_bar_bg_padding"
            android:top="@dimen/progress_bar_bg_padding" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <layer-list>
            <item
                android:bottom="@dimen/progress_bar_padding"
                android:left="@dimen/progress_bar_padding"
                android:right="@dimen/progress_bar_padding"
                android:top="@dimen/progress_bar_padding">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="@color/colorProgressBarGrey" />
                    <corners android:radius="@dimen/progress_bar_radius" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </clip>
</item>
```

My code is compiling fine if I turned off view Binding. but if turn on view Binding I am facing below error :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'.
```

> Unable to parse "android.widget.layer-list" as class in custom_profile_completion_progress.xml

My guess is it is happening due to layer-list as it is not a normal XML for user interface but it is part of some other xml. Any help to resolve it??

Answer (score 4):

Oppss, my bad. I have found the reason behind this. As view binding is for finding views available in layout folder. I put the drawable in layout folder instead of drawable folder. As it was in layout folder compiling was compiling to generate associate file and it was getting failed. And this makes sense. I put the xml in drawable folder, and it is working. Sharing this, it may help someone in future.